# Disable click in input in <a> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have an input text inside a button like this:

```
<a onclick="reply_click();" class="btn btn-app btn-app-spinner">
<input type="text" disabled  class="form-control small-input">
Set Budget
</a>
```

this is the result: 
[image]

The problem is that when the user clicks on the input text, the reply_click() is triggered. I would it to be triggered ONLY when he clicks on the a element (Set Bid).

How can I do it?

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deligeli/fkeozjha/)

**EDITED**
As you can see I want to make it look similar to the buttons in the design as you can see in the JSfiddle

Comment: Why on earth would you put a button *inside* a link? Pick one or the other...not both! If a link doesn't go somewhere... **don't use a link**.

Comment: it matches the design. I have other buttons with no input and it makes it look sexy

Comment: It should match the design **graphically**. Does the design requires nesting `input` inside a link????

Comment: no. it requires it to look the same

Comment: why don't you use a <span onclick="reply_click()">Set Bid</span> if you want to trigger the onclick only if the user click on the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this:

```
<div class="btn btn-app btn-app-spinner">
      <input type="text" class="form-control small-input">
      <a onclick="reply_click();" >
          Set Budget
      </a>
</div>
```

In your fiddle replace your html with the html that I provide on the answer and you will have what you want.

The trick is that adding the same classes that you have in your `a` to another element they are going to look like similar.

Then if you want your action fired when user clicks on the "set budget", wrap it with the `<a>`

Comment: I just added style="color:#666" to have the color not blue but looks like the other buttons. this is cool.

Answer (score 7):

Putting an `input` *inside* an `a` element is invalid HTML. From [the spec for `a`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> Content model:
>
> [Transparent](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#transparent), but there must be no [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendant.

[`input`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) is interactive content, so it cannot appear within an `a`. Browsers may well choose to rewrite your HTML to put the `input` *after* the `a` to try to make it valid.

So the solution here is not to put an `input` inside an `a`. Not only because HTML doesn't allow it (you could work around that with a click handler on a `div`), but because it's extremely unusual UX, which will be unfamiliar and likely uncomfortable to users.

---

Having said that, if a browser doesn't relocate the `input` (or if you replace the `a` with a `div` with `click` handler), you can stop the event from propagating to the `a` by hooking `click` on the `input` and using `stopPropgation`:

```
$("a input").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}):
```

I'm not recommending it, though.

Comment: how would you create the above look and feel?

Comment: use a div rather than a link

Comment: @Dejell: Fundamentally, having an input inside a button is a **very** unusual UX. So while you probably *can* do it it (for instance, oliv37's idea is reasonable, a `div` with a `click` handler; you'll need the `stopPropgation` above with that, too; or break the overall thing up into the top part, the left and right sides around the input, and the bottom bit, and make them all anchors), it's going to be odd for your users, who won't have encountered this kind of thing before. So I'd step back and revisit the UX, rather than implementing this.

Comment: @IvanRodriguezTorres: Your answer *doesn't* provide the look & feel the OP has asked for, as the "button" as a whole is not clickable, only `Set Budget` text.

Comment: Sir @T.J.Crowder can i get your email. I need to ask you several of question.? :))

Comment: Thanks. I guess that I will want to use a valid form, so I will drop the clickable option from the rest of the div, and just by clicking on the letters

Comment: @IvanRodriguezTorres: No, that's a compromise (one the OP was happy with). He wanted the whole button except the `input`. So the edges left and right of the input, the bit above the input, etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see I missed the point. Thank you for clarify this, and I apologize for the inconvenience

Answer (score 3):

In theory you can achieve the effect you're looking for with something like this

```
$(".setBid").click(function(e){
    var $input = $(this).find("input[type='text']");

    if ($input.is(e.target)
    {
        //do action
    }
})
```

here's the html

```
<a class="btn btn-app btn-app-spinner setBid">
    <input type="text" disabled  class="form-control small-input">
    Set Budget
</a>
```

however, as @TJ said this is NOT valid HTML

Answer (score 3):

This is invalid html! don't do that!

---

If you must, then just stop propagation by handling a click on the input:

```js
function reply_click(e){
   alert("clicked!");
}

function input_click(e)
{
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="reply_click();" class="btn btn-app btn-app-spinner">
  <input type="text" class="form-control small-input" onclick="input_click(event)">
  Set Budget
</a>
```

This snippet is not cross-browser safe (tested in chrome). Use jQuery, or handle the way other browsers deal with events.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `div` and use the `click` on that div. That way you have valid HTML.

```js
function bid(){
   alert('bid');
}

function stop(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
div {
  width:200px;
  height:60px;
  background-color:#f93;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="bid()">
  <input type='text' onclick="stop(event)">
  <p>bid</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not wrap the `input` element inside a link.

Instead, the [`input` needs a label](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html) (for accessibility, especially screen reader users) and something that functions as a button (a real `button` element in the code below). Since you don't have a proper `label` element, I used [WAI-ARIA `described-by`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#Descriptions_describedby) to link the input field with the button.

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="form-control small-input" 
   aria-describedby="ses-budget" />
<br />
<button type="submit" onclick="reply_click();" 
  class="btn btn-app btn-app-spinner" id="set-budget">Set budget</button>
</form>
```